# Getting UniqueResult in Criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am working with criteria query. But my following criteria isn’t working…

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AgencyDetail.class,”AgencyDetail”)
.add(Restrictions.eq(“AgencyDetail.agencyId”, agencyId)).add(Restrictions.eq(“AgencyDetail.active”, ‘Y’));
agencyDetail = (AgencyDetail)criteria.uniqueResult();
agencyId = agencyDetail.getAgencyId();
```

I can get the criteria object. But the error seems in the `criteria.uniqueResult();`

Comment: Can you show the mapping for `AgencyDetail` ?

Comment: Can you post your error log as well?

Comment: Define "isn't working". If you ask us to debug your code you could at least write a proper bug report, which describes both expected and actual behavior. That doesn't take much of your time, but will save us plenty of guess work.

Answer (score 0):

You are aheading a complicated way to go, there is no need to define an alias for the entity class you are finding except the entity class's association. you just try this, it will work:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AgencyDetail.class)
  .add(Restrictions.eq("agencyId", agencyId))
  .add(Restrictions.eq("active", 'Y'));
agencyDetail = (AgencyDetail)criteria.uniqueResult();
agencyId = agencyDetail.getAgencyId();
```

Comment: Oh Thanks EveryBody! The Problem got Solved. Actually i had no such field as agencyId in my agencyTable... It was in the agencyDetail Table.